# How to add Scala API documentation in IDEA on linux

Tags: linux, scala, api, intellij-idea, installation

I've installed Scala from repos on Gentoo with doc USE flag. 
Adding path to Scala compiler caused no problems.
But when I try to add docs in IDEA using path variables in module settings nothing happens.
Path to the documentation is /usr/share/doc/scala*/html/

[image: Settings screenshot]

[image: Documentation viewed after pressing Ctrl-q]